# Garbage data from GPS receiver

Tags: gps, node-red, nmea

I am trying to implement a GPS receiver into a system, using the data from it in Node-RED. It works most of the time, but every once in a while, the system crashes. I am using a netvar-receiver node, and the data seems valid. Somehow, though, from time to time, some data is missing in my output. I then connected the GPS receiver directly to a serial port, and was surprised to see a huge number of lines (I read out the GPRMC data) with weird (=non-alphanumeric) or missing characters in the logged data from it. I am connected serially @4800 baud.
My theory is this: When connecting through other equipment, something handles filtering the data, so the bad data isn't delivered further through the NR flow.
Example of directly monitored output:
`$GPRMC,114742.00,V,0000.00000,N,000‚r‚‚‚‚‚b*±0.000,,061219,,,N*60` (notice that this is invalid ("V") data, but the problem occurs with output marked "A" as well, and many lines with "V" look fine, too).
Another example: `$GPRMC,115125.00,V,0000.00000,N,00000.00000,E,0.000,061219,,,N*66` (fun fact: When typing this, one of those hex boxes is shown in the editing field right before `061219`, but it is gone in the output field)

Can anyone confirm that GPS data (NMEA 0183) is capable of crashing entire systems because of garbage characters?

Comment: if by system you mean computer then, in my opinion, the answer is no, corrupted data will not cause any crashes. But the underlying problem corrupting the data might. If you have, for instance, strong electromagnetic noise or external voltages feeding into your hardware through ground loops, they will certainly be able to complete crash or reboot a computer. NEMEA data should only have ASCII characters, if you are receiving those weird characters (non-ASCII) you should try to find out why they are there. Often times it will be a hardware issue (loose cables or differences in GND levels)

Comment: The system is in this case not a computer per se, but a PLC running alongside an integrated Linux. The GPS is connected to the serial port of the PLC and the data is read in the PLC and passed to variable herein. The received data (when testing on my PC) contains all sorts of characters, including bell/ring and also what seems to be way off the ASCII table, like "plus/minus sign" etc. However, I have just tested with an older version of the same GPS receiver, and with this, everything seems fine, so as of now, defective hardware seems to be the most plausible cause.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone confirm that GPS data (NMEA 0183) is capable of crashing entire systems because of garbage characters?

Well, no, your app should defend against invalid data no matter how it comes in.  If the line is invalid, reject it.  If a line is too long, reject it.

> I then connected the GPS receiver directly to a serial port, and was surprised to see a huge number of lines (I read out the GPRMC data) with weird (=non-alphanumeric)...

Your GPS unit is likely speaking dual protocol.  Most units these days support a binary protocol in addition to NMEA.  Check the documentation on your specific unit to figure out how to switch protocols.

Comment: The available Node-RED nodes that can handle the input may regrettably not be able to filter all erroneous data, so this might need to be handled in the PLC part of the system, if possible. The GPS receiver is this model: https://www.sanav.com/gm-44ub-fb.html and is set up with the standard communication parameters required. As described in the comment above, the problem seems to lie in the new model being defective as opposed to an older version of the receiver (same make and model). I have several units of the new model lying around, and they all seem faulty (so far 3+ units tested). :-(

Comment: @KMBN Out of curiosity, is it actually RS232, like that site says?  Not RS485?

Comment: Definitely RS-232. The older version works perfectly, with the only downside being that coordinates have one less decimal, making it potentially slightly less accurate.